# Xcode iPhone application vanishes after a while

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have created a simple application for my iPhone SE (iOS 15.1). I use it almost everyday, building and running it from Xcode (version 13.2 beta) with my device as the target; the app thus gets installed and I can use it for about a day. After a while, I couldn't say how long exactly, if I try to launch it on my iPhone an error message appears stating that the application is not available. How can I change that behavior and let Xcode know that I want to install it for keeps?

I guess the answer must lie somewhere in the "build settings" page of my applications, but I lose my bearings in this maze of options. I'd be most grateful if someone could help me figure that out.

With thanks,
Julien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Unless you put it on the AppStore. This is because of the Provisioning of the App.

You have four Options:

- Free provisioning (no paid developer account) is good for **one week**.
- TestFlight distribution (via Xcode and a purchased developer account) is good for **90 days**.
- Local/ad-hoc installs (via Xcode and a purchased developer account), to a device registered in the Member Center, are good for **max one year**, but not longer than time left on the dev's annual paid account. See https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev7ccaf4d3c
- Apps on the store are re-signed by Apple and **never expire**.

Comment: TestFlight distribution is 90 days afaik.

Comment: Good catch @Fogmeister . Forgot they extended it. Updating Answer.